# oledbcommandbuilder.driveparameters get duplicate stored proceduer parameters count

Tags: c#, asp.net

After importing new dump to oracle db, `oledbcommandbuilder.driveparameters` which exist in `sqlhelperparametercache` class return duplicate parameter count which cause exception:

> parameter count doesn't match parameter value count

Currently I have to use **schema/owner** name  to get valid parameter count number for a procedure
while I wasn't before .

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You must use owner name if you have multiple schemas with the same structure or it will get this error because it considers each procedure in each schema diffrent so it will return the sum of thier input parameters.